# On hiding the visibilty of an image icon the adjacent Image takes the x,y cordinates of hidden control

Tags: c#, css

I have two image icons, based on some condition I like to set the visible property of one of the images to false. For ex one is an arrow image and the other is folder image icon. 
On setting folder image icon to false the arrow image takes place of the folder image.

How to avoid moving of the image?

Design page:

```
<td style="height:15px;padding-right:5px;width: 18px;vertical-align:top;">
    <asp:LinkButton id="lnkDownload" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="imgArrow" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/DownloadIcon2.png" ToolTip="Download Item" style="vertical-align: middle;padding-bottom:0px;" Height="17px" Width="17px"/>
    </asp:LinkButton>
</td>
<td style="height:15px;padding-right:5px;width: 18px;vertical-align:top;">
    <asp:LinkButton id="lnkAddtoDownload" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="imgfolder" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/DownloadIcon1.png" ToolTip="Add to grid" style="vertical-align: middle;padding-bottom:0px;" Width="17px" Height="17px" />
    </asp:LinkButton>
</td>
```

**Code behind:**

```
if(doc == weburl)
    imgfolder.Visible = false;
```

Have attached the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you were dynamically give any icon needing to be hidden a class of "hide", you could create a CSS rule like this:

```
.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

that way you wouldn't see it, but it would still take up physical space.